# Azure AD: Requesting a token using device code failed with 401

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, adal

I am trying to use Azure AD with device code flow. I've created an application and tried to request a code using this client id. The request to code succeed and I was able to approve the login. But, when I tried to request a token using the device code, the request failed with the following error:

```
AADSTS70002: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion'.
```

As far as I can tell, this flow does not require any credentials so I am not sure why this error occurred. I was able to reproduce it using different languages and different Adal libraries (NodeJS, C#) and also by using Postman. So I am pretty sure this is not a bug in a specific library. Probably something I misconfigured - although it is unclear to me what. Could you help me figure this out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to use confidential client (web app) to execute a flow that is meant for public clients. Please create a native client application to execute the flow.

Comment: Why does it matter, I may have a serverless SPA app and want to use this flow to keep client secret out of user access, is this possible?